# how can we load usercontrol using generic handler?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, generics, user-controls, handler

i want to load a user control using jquery ajax. One possible i found is to load usercontrol through generic handler. Anyone help me plsss. here the ajax code i am using to call the control.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function fillSigns() { 
                $.ajax({
                    url: "usercontrolhandler.ashx?control=signs.ascx",
                    context: document.body,
                    success: function (data) {                       
                        $('#signdiv').html(data);
                    }
                });
            }  
 </script>
```

and here is the code in handler file

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        Page page = new Page();
        UserControl ctrl = (UserControl)page.LoadControl("~/" + context.Request["control"] + ".ascx");      
        page.Form.Controls.Add(ctrl);

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
        ctrl.RenderControl(tw);
        context.Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
    }
```

This code raises object reference not found error at below shown line.

```
 page.Form.Controls.Add(ctrl);
```

Comment: There is no need to create a `Page` object to render the `UserControl`. Remove that code and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `page.Form` is `null` here, that's why you've got a null reference exception. You could add your user control to the page's control collection instead:

```
page.Controls.Add(ctrl);
```

You could also use [`HttpServerUtility.Execute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150027.aspx) method for page rendering:

```
StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, output, false);
```

And finally take a look onto [Tip/Trick: Cool UI Templating Technique to use with ASP.NET AJAX for non-UpdatePanel scenarios](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/10/22/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Cool-UI-Templating-Technique-to-use-with-ASP.NET-AJAX-for-non_2D00_UpdatePanel-scenarios.aspx) article by Scott Guthrie which covers your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Page page = new Page {ViewStateMode = ViewStateMode.Disabled};
HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm { ViewStateMode = ViewStateMode.Disabled };
form.Controls.Add(ctrl);
page.Controls.Add(form);
```

then:

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
page.RenderControl(tw);
context.Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
```